# Pressflow 5 and Varnish

Tags: drupal, caching, performance, varnish

**We're currently running a site with:**
Pressflow 5.23.50
Varnish 2.1.4

I suspect some of the problems I'm running to are based on the wide variety of documentation and that some of it is up to date and some of it isn't.

**Currently I get these response headers:**

```
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.1.6
X-Drupal-Cache  HIT
Etag    "1294852404-1"
Cache-Control   public, max-age=0
Last-Modified   Wed, 12 Jan 2011 17:13:24 GMT
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Vary    Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cacheable YES
Content-Length  7621
Date    Wed, 12 Jan 2011 17:59:49 GMT
X-Varnish   1305826372
Age 0
Via 1.1 varnish
Connection  keep-alive
X-Cache MISS
```

**Varnish Config:**
We are using the Global Redirect module and I have included the appropriate check as I've found online in it.

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "7900";
#     .connect_timeout = 600s;
#     .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
#     .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
#     .max_connections = 25000;
}


sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend = default;



  set req.grace = 5m;

    remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

    # Properly handle different encoding types
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

# Force lookup if the request is a no-cache request from the client
    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
        return (pass);
    }

    ## Default request checks
    if (req.request != "GET" &&
        req.request != "HEAD" &&
        req.request != "PUT" &&
        req.request != "POST" &&
        req.request != "TRACE" &&
        req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.request != "DELETE") {
            # Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird.
            return (pipe);
    }
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
        return (pass);
    }

    ## Modified from default to allow caching if cookies are set, but not http auth
    if (req.http.Authorization) {
        /* Not cacheable by default */
        return (pass);
    }

    ## Remove has_js and Google Analytics cookies.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(__[a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
    ## Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
    ## Remove empty cookies.
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    ## Catch Drupal theme files  - THIS BREAKS UPDATE.PHP DO NOT USE
    #if (req.url ~ "^/sites/") {
    #    unset req.http.Cookie;
    #}
    # Catch Drupal misc files (like drupal.js and jquery.js)
    #if (req.url ~ "^/misc/") {
    #    unset req.http.Cookie;
    #}
    # Drupal js/css doesn't need cookies, cache them
    if (req.url ~ "^/modules/.*\.(js|css)\?") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    ## Pass cron jobs and server-status
    if (req.url ~ "cron.php") {
       return (pass);
    }
    ## Don't cache install
    if (req.url ~ "install.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # if (req.url ~ "index.php") {
#   unset req.http.Cookie;
#     }

    # This is for Global Redirect.
    if (req.url ~ "node\?page=[0-9]+$") {
             set req.url = regsub(req.url, "node(\?page=[0-9]+$)", "\1");
             return (lookup);
    }

    ## Don't cache Drupal logged-in user sessions
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(VARNISH|DRUPAL_UID)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (lookup);
}

# Per-session cache
sub vcl_hash { if (req.http.Cookie) { set req.hash += req.http.Cookie; } }

sub vcl_fetch {
    # These status codes should always pass through and never cache.
    if (beresp.status == 404 || beresp.status == 503 || beresp.status == 500) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO: beresp.status";
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable-status = beresp.status;
        return (pass);
    }

    # Grace to allow varnish to serve content if backend is lagged
    set beresp.grace = 5m;


    if (!beresp.cacheable) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO: !beresp.cacheable";
        return (pass);
    }

    # All tests passed, therefore item is cacheable
    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
    return (deliver);
}
#
sub vcl_deliver {
#    return (deliver);
   #add cache hit data
   if (obj.hits > 0) {
     #if hit add hit count
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
     set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
   } else {
     set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
   }
}

sub vcl_error {
    if (obj.status == 503 && req.restarts < 5) {
        set obj.http.X-Restarts = req.restarts;
        restart;
    }
}
```

I've also added this to the bottom of settings.php:

```
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1');
```

I also have Drupal set to "Aggressive Caching" on the performance page.

Is there some little thing I'm missing or maybe a direction someone could point me towards on other things to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many modules will either start a session or add a cookie that will cause the page to not be cacheable. There are a number of possibilities and solutions found here:

https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Modules+that+break+caching,+and+how+to+fix+them

some tips on debugging which module is starting a session.

http://groups.drupal.org/node/66888

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the lullabot article too:

Configuring Varnish for High-Availability with Multiple Web Servers

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/varnish-multiple-web-servers-drupal

They have a full varnish config for drupal to start from, as well as a proper varnish status check php script.